# Using icons in bootstrap menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add my own icons to a bootstrap menu but they aren't appearing. I was wondering if i'm editing the wrong part of the CSS? Below is my code and the website is here: http://sc580.student.eda.kent.ac.uk/ExploreCanterbury/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Explore Canterbury</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="LocMenu"><span class="#LocIcon"></span></a></li>
              <li><a href="PhotoMenu"><span class="#photosIcon"></span></a></li>
              <li><a href="InfoMenu"><span class="#infoIcon"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

.photosIcon {
  background-image:url(img/photos.png);
  width:100px;
  heigth:100px;
}

.infoIcon {
  background-image:url(img/information.png);
  width:100px;
  heigth:100px;
}
```

Comment: You realise with images instead of text that your menu will be invisible to screenreaders...right?

Comment: Classes begin with `#` are invalid

Comment: _“I was wondering if i'm editing the wrong part of the CSS?”_ – your browser’s developer tools are an efficient way to find stuff such as this out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom icon in Twitter Bootstrap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393325/how-to-add-custom-icon-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: You should read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393325/how-to-add-custom-icon-in-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Remove the #'s in these lines:

```
<li><a href="LocMenu"><span class="#LocIcon"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="PhotoMenu"><span class="#photosIcon"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="InfoMenu"><span class="#infoIcon"></span></a></li>
```

Now, fix your misspelled HEIGHT, and wrap your css in style tags like so:

```
<style>
.photosIcon {
background-image:url(img/photos.png);
width:100px;
heigHT:100px;
}
.infoIcon {
background-image:url(img/information.png);
width:100px;
heigHT:100px;
}
</style>
```

And viola.

Comment: I edited my response after finding a few more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your class names should not start with a `#`.

```
<li><a href="LocMenu"><span class="#LocIcon"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="PhotoMenu"><span class="#photosIcon"></span></a></li>
<li><a href="InfoMenu"><span class="#infoIcon"></span></a></li>
```

this should be:

```
 <li><a href="LocMenu"><span class="LocIcon"></span></a></li>
 <li><a href="PhotoMenu"><span class="photosIcon"></span></a></li>
 <li><a href="InfoMenu"><span class="infoIcon"></span></a></li>
```

you would then reference the class in `css` by prepending `.` to the classname as you have done.

```
<style>

.photosIcon {
  width: 100px
  ...
}
.infoIcon {
  width: 100px
  ...
}

</style>
```

For id's you would prepend with `#` in css.

`<div id="mydiv"></div>`

would be referenced like so in css:

```
<style>

#mydiv{
   width: 100px;
...
}

</style>
```

Comment: thank you :) i have changed that but still the images don't seem to be appearing!

Comment: The site you have linked in the question is not available

Comment: @user3005003 are you sure the files exist in the directory?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've resolved the syntactic issues (from the other answers), your remaining issue may lie in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838847/html-and-css-background-image-is-not-showing-up) about the CSS `background-image`.